# Reuse the same arraylist in android application

Tags: android, arraylist

When I start the app, I am getting `Arraylist` of my `Pojo` object with complex logic and I need to access the same arraylist from different fragments,activities, classes and the `Arraylist` will be deleted after app is closed.

Currently I am thinking of making singleton class and storing the `Arraylist` in it, is there any better solution ?

Comment: You can save it using complex preferences, do you want the implementation(so you don't lose it when you close the app) ? and to access it from all the activities you can make it global static

Comment: @Badran no,I need to get fresh arraylist every time I open the app.

Comment: oh okay , then go for @Umang solution ! good luck

Answer (score 2):

Making a Singleton class and storing an ArrayList for situations like these is one the best ideas.

Go ahead and implement it.

Also, on the other hand, you can make the ArrayList static and access it throughout the app.

Comment: Is there any performance difference if I will hold it in my `Utils` class as private filed with static setter and getter?

Comment: I would not recommend to make static setter getters. Make the arraylist as static.

If you need an implementation example follow the link below:

https://alvinalexander.com/source-code/java/how-create-populate-static-list-arraylist-linkedlist-syntax-in-java